# How to looping array data by category dan sum amount each category

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a data array containing category, description and amount, like the following.

```
$arr = [
[1, "Category 1", "Desc 1", 10000],
    [2, "Category 1", "Desc 2", 5000],
    [3, "Category 1", "Desc 3", 2500],
    [4, "Category 1", "Desc 4", 3000],
    [5, "Category 1", "Desc 5", 15000],
    [1, "Category 2", "Ket 1", 10000],
    [2, "Category 2", "Ket 2", 5000],
    [3, "Category 2", "Ket 3", 2500],
    [1, "Category 3", "Kata 1", 3000],
    [2, "Category 3", "Kata 2", 15000],
];
```

From that data, I want to display it according to its category, and add up the value for each category, as follows.

```
Category 1
1. Desc 1 - 10000
2. Desc 2 - 5000
3. Desc 3 - 2500
4. Desc 4 - 3000
5. Desc 5 - 15000
Total = 35500
Category 2
1. Ket 1 - 10000
2. Ket 2 - 5000
3. Ket 3 - 2500
Total = 17500
Category 3
1. Kata 1 - 3000
2. Kata 2 - 15000
Total = 18000
```

To display data by category, here's the code I made:

https://onlinephp.io/c/ca850

```
$array = [
    [1, "Category 1", "Desc 1", 10000],
    [2, "Category 1", "Desc 2", 5000],
    [3, "Category 1", "Desc 3", 2500],
    [4, "Category 1", "Desc 4", 3000],
    [5, "Category 1", "Desc 5", 15000],
    [1, "Category 2", "Ket 1", 10000],
    [2, "Category 2", "Ket 2", 5000],
    [3, "Category 2", "Ket 3", 2500],
    [1, "Category 3", "Kata 1", 3000],
    [2, "Category 3", "Kata 2", 15000],
];

$cat = '';
$x = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
    if ($data[1] != $cat) {
        echo $data[1] . PHP_EOL;
        $cat = $data[1];
    }
    
    echo $data[0] . ". " . $data[2] . " - " . $data[3] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
Category 1
1. Desc 1 - 10000
2. Desc 2 - 5000
3. Desc 3 - 2500
4. Desc 4 - 3000
5. Desc 5 - 15000
Category 2
1. Ket 1 - 10000
2. Ket 2 - 5000
3. Ket 3 - 2500
Category 3
1. Kata 1 - 3000
2. Kata 2 - 15000
```

How can I add up the amount for each category?

Answer (score 1):

Sum it into a variable and reset it when the category changes.

```
$cat = '';
$x = 0;
$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
    if ($data[1] != $cat) {
        if ($key > 0) {
            echo 'Total: ', $total, PHP_EOL;
            $total = 0;
        }
        echo $data[1] . PHP_EOL;
        $cat = $data[1];
    }
    
    echo $data[0] . ". " . $data[2] . " - " . $data[3] . PHP_EOL;
    $total += $data[3];
}
echo 'Total: ', $total, PHP_EOL;
```